# Kotlin: Exoplayer is not playing the video

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am learning Kotlin and Exoplayer and I am making an app that allows the user to select a video and play it on the next screen. However, after starting Intent, the selected video is not played.

First Activity:

```
private fun openGallery() {
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        intent.type = "video/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {

            val selectedMediaUri = data!!.getData()
            if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("video")) {
                //handle video

                // Get selected gallery image
                val selectedVideo = data.getData()
                // Get and resize profile image
                val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
                val cursor = applicationContext.contentResolver.query(selectedVideo!!, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
                cursor!!.moveToFirst()

                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
                val videoStoragePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                cursor.close()

                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,PostarVideoActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("path",videoStoragePath)
                startActivity(intent)

            }

        }
```

Second Activity:

```
val path = intent.extras!!.getString("path")
        Log.i("mypath", path)

val player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(applicationContext)
        videoPreview.player = player

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            applicationContext,
            Util.getUserAgent(applicationContext, applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
        )
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        val videoSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(path!!))
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(videoSource)
```

How to resolve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should start by looking into your logcat. If you can't figure it out then update your question with some logs that might help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was simple ...
Just request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions

This can be easily resolved with the [Dexter library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter).
Maybe this can help someone